# Does the PHB+1 character-building limit in Adventurers League include spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-creation, dnd-adventurers-league

I’m thinking of trying out a Hexblade Warlock in Adventurers League, which limits players to PHB+1 for character-building.

The problem I have with this is that the Hexblade is from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, but I really want the *booming blade* cantrip as well from the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*. Is this legal in Adventurers League play?

Comment: related: [What is the +1 rule?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110848/23970)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Choosing a Warlock pact from one +1 and a cantrip from another +1 is not AL legal.

As a warlock (and not of the Tome), the only way you learn spells is either by selection at creation or upon advancing a level.

That you can only use materials from PHB+1 for creation-choices is well detailed in the first page of the [Adventurers League Player's Guide](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack). So you cannot, at creation, choose both Hexblade and *booming blade*.

Now flip to the last page of the ALPG, "Character Advancement."

> Feats and spells gained by advancement are subject to PHB+1.

So you can't gain *booming blade* through advancement, either.

---

Note that spells *copied into a spellbook* do not fall victim to the +1 restriction, as they're neither gained at creation nor through advancement. But note further, that's a *spellbook,* not a [*grimiore*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83281/23970)

Answer (score 4):

> The problem I have with this is that the Hexblade is from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, but I really want the *booming blade* cantrip as well from the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*. Is this legal in Adventurers League play?

### No.

"Plus one" means only **one** "plus one" per character.

From the [Adventurers League Player's Guide](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/AL_PH_SKT.pdf) linked on the [AL Resources](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources) page:

> In addition to the Player’s Handbook however, you may also choose to use ***one*** other resource from those listed below to build your character.